# How to write a trigger to enforce the following business rule:?

Tags: mysql, triggers

each department has only one manager. Use trigger template for ensuring this business rule while new rows are inserted into Employees:

```
 Employees(employeeNumber, lastName, firstName, DOB, HireDate, Position,
          Salary, Dept)
 Primary Key: employeeNumber
 Foreign key: Dept refers to DeptID in Departments
 Departments(DeptID, DeptName, DeptLocation)
 Primary Key: DeptID
```

CREATE TRIGGER TR_MANAGER BEFORE INSERT ON Employees FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END

Comment: The scheme is wrong. You must revert it - the department table must contain a column with employee id.

Comment: I suggest a junction table consisting of dept and employee.